# What is 'Persuasive Data'?

Tags: conference, data, abstract

I'm submitting an abstract for the World Molecular Imaging Conference and they advise:

> Please include a Persuasive Data file if you would like your abstract to be considered for an oral presentation. Persuasive data should include figure captions that explain the results of the figure without requiring the reviewer to re-read the main text.

The Persuasive data file should be .pdf or .doc

I have never come across this format before, does anyone know what a persuasive data file is? I'm guessing either extended abstract or actual experimental data?

Comment: I've never heard of this before, but the term is probably specific to this scientific field. I'd guess "data" in Molecular Imaging is actually an image. You can always ask the organisers of the conference if your advisor doesn't know the term either.

Comment: I don't know about your field, so I'd follow Roland's advice ... but in some fields the term refers to pretty charts or other figures to explain the crux of your argument.  Think of it as an elevator speach in picture form.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is an infographic/data visualization which includes a graphic summary of your results, can be a chart, a graph an image etc. One must be able to view it and be exposed to the main results/conclusions.